# Efficient conversion from String[] to F# List

Tags: collections, casting, f#

I'm coming to F# from a C# background and a little behind on the different lists and collections. I recently ran into a case where I needed to go from a string[] to 'T list. I ended up using list comprehension to do the cast:

```
let lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\LinesOText.txt") // returns a string array
let listOLines = [for l in lines -> l] // use list comprehension to get the f# list
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing the conversion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`List.ofArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370614.aspx) or [`Array.toList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353606.aspx).

Comment: @JoshuaBelden: I think you're observing other factors at play, they both call [the same internal function](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L408-413). See [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs#L134) and [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L48).

Comment: Yep, if in doubt, reverse engineer it.  The F# code base is a great source of information.  I could do with a little plugin so you could hit show definitions and it took you to the github repo...

Answer (score 3):

this should do it:

```
let lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\LinesOText.txt") |> List.ofArray
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it:

```
let listOfLines = [yield! File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\LinesOText.txt")]
```

Comment: I really like the syntax here but on an array 0f 100k ints, it's about 25% slower than Array.toList and List.ofArray.

Comment: Being a language construct, `yield!` is more general and requires more plumbing. I included it mostly for completeness; it saves a few keystrokes when performance isn't a concern.